# How to apply force at an speicific angle in spriteKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, vector, sprite-kit

I want to give Force to my `SKSpriteNode` at specific angle.
So, How to treat my `CGVector` for give force at specific angle?

I had searched for it but unfortunately not getting any good way.

**What i wants to achieve :**

My `SKSpriteNode` moving towards the screen. There are buttons on top like 30,45,60.
So if user press button(i.e. that Button contain "30") then i had to move my `SKSpriteNode` to 30 degree with same speed.

Please help me towards it if any of you can help me regarding this.

Comment: @sangony ,  Thanks for your quick response. I will see it and will let you knew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you will need to convert the angle in degrees to radians by multiplying it by pi / 180

```
CGFloat angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * M_PI / 180;
```

You can then determine the vector components in that direction by

```
CGFloat dx = cosf(angleInRadians);
CGFloat dy = sinf(angleInRadians);
```

and finally apply a force to the sprite with

```
[sprite.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(dx*scale, dy*scale)];
```

where `scale` determines how much force is applied.

Optionally, you can rotate the sprite to face in the same direction as its motion by

```
sprite.zRotation = angleInRadians + offset;
```

where `offset` is the difference in angle, in radians, between your sprite's image and zero degrees. For example, if your sprite is facing up when `zRotation` is zero, `offset` should be `-M_PI_2`.

Comment: Hi, 0x141E, Actually force on my sprite did applied. First i need to stop my sprite from previous force effect. Then need to force that my sprite will go in specific angle.

Comment: You can stop your sprite with `sprite.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0);`

Comment: 0x141E Here i am able to stop sprite. but not able to move my sprite in specific direction(i.e. with respective angle)

Comment: I suggest you replace `applyForce` with `applyImpulse` and increase `scale` until the sprite moves as you expect.

Comment: This doesn't work, dx is always positive no matter which direction I rotate my object, so it always moves towards the right. Also, dy is always incredibly small (negligible) so all my objects are moving to the right of the screen

Comment: @Minimi are you using the object's `zRotation` to calculate `dx` and  dy`? If not, what are the values of the angles you are using?

Comment: Yea I'm using zRotation, so my angles are 45, 135, 225, and 315 (splitting the coordinate system into 8 equal pieces). In radians these are pi / 4, 3pi/4, 5pi/4, 7pi/4. I then use sin and cos on these radian angles, and multiply the result by 100. I then use this as the force, but the behavior I mentioned above keeps happening

Comment: @Minimi if you take the sin/cos of those radian angles you should get (0.7071,0.7071), (-0.7071,0.7071), (-0.7071,-0.7071), and (0.7071,-0.7071) which will cause the object to move right/up, left/up, left/down, and right/down, respectively.

Comment: You're right it was a typo, I thought I was going crazy!